# How to calculate slowing effect of a planets gravity on a projectile that is launched upwards

Tags: gravity, physics, velocity

The acceleration a ballistic projectile would experience at a certain height above a planet (neglecting any atmosphere) is given by

$$a = -\frac{GM}{(R + h)^2}$$

where

- $G$ is the gravitational constant $6.67 \times 10^{-11}$ m<sup>3</sup>s<sup>-2</sup>kg<sup>-1</sup>
- $h$ is the altitude above the planet's surface in meters
- $M$ is the planet's mass in kg
- $R$ is the planet's radius in meters

I need an expression with which I can get current height $h$, time and remaining velocity $v_r$ through the initial velocity $v_i$ the projectile starts with and the variables listed above.

Comment: looks like a fairly simple calculus problem to me

Comment: @JCRM exactly. A link might do too, if you don't think it's worth your time.

Comment: I believe the magic words you're looking for are [radial elliptic trajectory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radial_trajectory). Knowing where this question arose, I can tell you that I _tried_ to make use of this but it seemed too much like hard work, which is why I fudged things with a lower apoapsis and a plain old parabolic.

Comment: @StarfishPrime thanks for your help, again. I tried reading into some papers about eliptic trajectories and saw half a dozen symbols I don't know the name of. What do I even need a second dimension for? Can't like two thrids of this be avoided by aiming straight upwards? + Do the equations 13 and 14 look somewhat fitting for what I'm looking for? https://arxiv.org/pdf/physics/0310049.pdf

Comment: @StarfishPrime aaah. Once again I forgot tidally locked planets still rotate around their axis. Now I'd have to decide if they would want to build the fountain at a pole. I don't see much speaking against it, but why would my alien scientists be as lazy as I am? I guess it's time to decide what distance the planet has from its sun, but I can't know that without knowing how heavy the planet is and I can't know how heavy the planet has to be in order for my aliens not being able to leave, when I don't know how they'd build a space fountain. Arrrrgh

Comment: You might want to move over to WorldBuilding.SE if you're starting to write a story

Comment: @CarlWitthoft they don't like pure math questions

Comment: Where did the part of the question about the influence of other planets come from? That *massively* complicates the issue, and seems to change the whole point of the question.

Comment: I nearly rolled it back when I saw it @OrganicMarble --  but https://space.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1419/

Comment: @OrganicMarble I think I see what happened. The title says "effect of a planets" (and not planet's with an apostrophe) and I mis-read it as "effect of planets", missing the "a". Luckily I don't write software for Boeing (but maybe it wouldn't hurt, considering their batting average?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some observations you can make, before attempting any calculus with respect to time.

First, there's the potential energy of the gravity well of the planet:

$$E_{potential} = -\frac{GMm}{r}$$

Thus, if the projectile has enough kinetic energy, it can escape:

$$E_{kinetic} + E_{potential} > 0$$

$$\frac{v_i^2m}{2} -\frac{GMm}{R+h_i} > 0$$

$$\frac{v_i^2}{2} -\frac{GM}{R+h_i} > 0$$

Otherwise, it will fall back. In that case, it will reach a certain maximulm altitude $h_{max}$, which we can calculate since it will have zero kinetic energy there:

$$\frac{v_i^2}{2} -\frac{GM}{R+h_i} = -\frac{GM}{R+h_{max}}$$
$$(R+h_{max})\left(\frac{v_i^2}{2} -\frac{GM}{R+h_i}\right) = -GM$$
$$h_{max}\left(\frac{v_i^2}{2} -\frac{GM}{R+h_i}\right) = -GM - R\left(\frac{v_i^2}{2} -\frac{GM}{R+h_i}\right)$$
$$h_{max} = -\frac{GM}{\frac{v_i^2}{2} -\frac{GM}{R+h_i}} - R$$

In the case id *does* escape, the velocity will decrease to a certain $v_{\infty}$:

$$v_{\infty} =\sqrt{v_i^2 -\frac{2GM}{R+h_i}}$$

Comment: thanks. I think that's as close to a solution one can get in this case.